# Flutter - Row of buttons with first and last having rounded end shape

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I build a row of buttons with rounded left and right ends in Flutter? I'd like to add something like this to my first flutter app. The example on imgur.com is taken from the Messaging app on my Huawei phone.

[image]

I can do a series of individual FloatingActionButton.extended that sit side by side in a row. Or a row of RaisedButtons with RoundedRectangleBorder. But these both look a bit strange - [Two rounded buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbZo0.jpg)

I guess something like

> shape: new LeftRoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new
>   BorderRadius.circular(30)),

followed by

> shape: new RightRoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new
>   BorderRadius.circular(30)),

might be ok, except they don't actually exist.

How should I put together my Widgets to make a toolbar at the bottom of my app like this? I guess I should also be open to this being a totally non-standard design, which is why I'm finding it a bit of a challenge to code.
Thanks.

Comment: You create a single button with two possible actions based on where a user touches. What happens if a user touches somewhere in between? Where an ink splash is going to stop? This is not a good UX design. You can group two buttons if they are logically connected, but don't make the container look like an actionable element, because it's not.

Comment: Thinking about it, maybe they look strange just because I've not included any padding between the buttons? I do like the look of the big single button with rounded ends - but I take Andrei's point of even if that could be produced doesn't mean it should be.  Still, it would be interesting to know how it could be coded :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
    class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
        height: 60.0,
        width: 250.0,
        child: Material(
          shape: StadiumBorder(),
          textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
          elevation: 6.0,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.horizontal(left: Radius.circular(50))),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                        Text("New Message")
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.horizontal(right: Radius.circular(50))),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.more_vert,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                        Text("More")
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent Ahmed - InkWell left and right properties are very good to learn. Thanks!

Comment: you dont need any `InkWell` - just use any material `Button` which builds `InkWell` under the hood during their `build()` method

Comment: Thanks @pskink I didn't know that about buttons. I've reworked the widgets to use Buttons with  

              `shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(left: Radius.circular(50))
                ),`

Comment: @cyteen02 yes, this is exactly what i meant - inside `RaisedButton` for example